# Bootstrap footer rotate issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, cordova, phonegap-build

I am creating an mobile app using HTML/CSS/JS with Bootstrap and PhoneGap Build.

In my app I have a footer on my pages with 3 navigation buttons. The problem is that when I rotate my device from portrait to landscape, the buttons do not resize to take up the full width like they are supposed to. However, if I click one of the nav buttons after rotating, the new page that loads does show the buttons at full width. Rotating once again back to portrait, now has the buttons taking up way too much space.

I am utilizing `<div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">` like the [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-groups-justified) states.

My footer HTML is as follows:

```
<nav id="footer" class="navbar-fixed-bottom col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4" role="navigation" style="padding: 0 0;">
    <div id="footerGroup" class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
        <a type="button" class="btn btn-default active" href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> Home</a>
        <a type="button" class="btn btn-default" href="fundHistoryPage.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify"></span> History</a>
        <a type="button" class="btn btn-default" href="calculatorPage.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-usd"></span> Calc</a>
    </div>
</nav>
```

I have also tried setting a resize event handler to remove the "btn-group-justified" class and re-add it but to no avail.

```
$( window ).resize(function(){
    $("#footerGroup").removeClass('btn-group-justified');
    $("#footerGroup").addClass('btn-group-justified');
});
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

Edit: The footer re-sizes perfectly when testing in the browser. Just not on test devices.

Comment: Not sure what you need, but works fine here. http://bootply.com/85933
Can provide the links to the page for us to test in mobile/tab devices? Hard to know the problem with dragging the browser size.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, forgot to mention that it works fine in browser, just not on the device itself. Edited my question to reflect that.

Comment: Usually, when I change the orientation of my website, I have to double tap to resize properly on mobile device. It's not automated and the space will stay the same if you change orientation.

Seing your code, the problem could come from different COL values (some are equal to 12, other to 10, one to 9 which can complicate the resizing of your bootstrap depending on your media-queries).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hate answering my own question but I am going to anyways. After playing around with it a bit last night I ended up employing the following:

```
$( window ).resize(function(){
    $("#footerGroup").removeClass('btn-group-justified');
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#footerGroup").addClass('btn-group-justified');
    }, 1);
});
```

I found that even a delay of just 1 millisecond before adding the class back in is enough to get it to resize properly. Very strange. Opened a new issue on the Bootstrap repo [here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/10978).

Answer (score 0):

```
<nav id="footer" class="navbar-fixed-bottom col-sm-12 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4" role="navigation" style="padding: 0 0;">
```

please maintain same sizes, providing multiple sizes may give you unwanted results